# How to perform sorting in datatables using jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

I have used this even though it is not workin..

Comment: Post a codepen including data tables, your data, examples, etc. This isn't enough to go on.

Comment: "sAjaxSource": "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/EmployeeData",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "firstName" },
            { "mData": "lastName" },
            { "mData": "emp_Id" },     
            { "mData": "email_ID" },
            { "mData": "phone_No" },
            { "mData": "city" },     
         My data i am displaying by this

Comment: This is a correct code, there is another reason the code is not working. Please update your question instead of posting code in the comments.

Comment: I want 4th column to sorted by desc order but it is not performiing what is the reason for that

Comment: I can see you've just copy/pasted that code from an example on [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html). You've then posted a bit of code using `sAjaxSource` which contradicts your first example.

Comment: what is the reason it is not getting

Comment: How are you populating the datatable? Show the code that does it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming based on your questing you are not able to sort your table by using jQuery plugins you have used.

> For sorting your table first of all you have to add css and js file (check in following code and then in javascript code  give your table ID (here id is example).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
</script>

    </head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Here I have taken sample data

Comment: I have added that files

Comment: Take mine code is it working or not tell me, If not tell me what error you r getting in your console.

Comment: only the data is getting displayed no sorting is performing

Comment: Check in console whats the problem.. r u getting any error in console? May be you are not properly adding jquery lib.

Comment: Do one thing paste your all html codes also, let us see what you have done.